# Using objects in hooks for forms

Tags: reactjs

I have just started with REACT and is looking for a valid approach when working with forms with many controls. And i dont need any validation so I skipped react-hook-forms.

Is there any recommended practices when working with forms? I have around 20 inputs so it is a semi large form. I started out having a hook for each input, but realized fast it was a little hard to maintain. So I changed to having one hook with an object like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bind-input-kzzd3

I can see some people recommend reducers for forms, is there anything wrong just using a hook with an object like my sample for simplicity? What will a reducer give me extra? Or would you go for a hook for each input?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { Row, Col, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from "reactstrap";

export default function App() {
  const onSearch = val => {
    alert(val);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GetSearchForm onSearch={onSearch} />
    </div>
  );
}

const GetSearchForm = props => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    accountId: 0,
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  });

  const onSearch = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onSearch(val);
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSearch}>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="exampleEmail">Account Id</Label>
            <Input
              type="number"
              name="account"
              id="account"
              placeholder="AccountId"
              onChange={e =>
                setFormData({ ...formData, accountId: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="firstName">Firstname</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              id="firstName"
              placeholder="Firstname"
              value={val}
              onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="exampleEmail">Lastname</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              id="lastName"
              placeholder="Lastname"
              value={val}
              onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Button>Submit</Button>

      <div>{JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2)}</div>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you referring to `useReducer` or redux reducer?

Comment: If you think you have some state that is better if it's grouped together then `useReducer` might be better instead of `useState`. It's kind of personal preference though.

Comment: useReducer but I might be worng. I am new to REACT but I understand Redux when you want to communicate between many components. This scenario is just a simple form on a page. So as I understand it REDUX would be to overcomplex it?

Comment: Yeah, you don't redux for that. useReducer might help you if you want to split the state updating logic. There you can use a switch statement and update the state as necessary for different cases. See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i dont need any validation so I skipped react-hook-forms.*

I assume that you are using a hook means React.useState. Yes, if you don't want to use other form library, it is perfectly fine to update your state that way. Just **be careful when you are updating state** in `useEffect`, there is a problem with closure, where state is not updated properly.

*any recommended practices when working with forms*

As mentioned above, be careful with closure, (state is not updated properly) I will advice to use a `setState((prevState)=>return your modified state)`.

*What will a reducer give me extra? Or would you go for a hook for each input?*

useReducer has more control for you to setState.

*I have around 20 inputs so it is a semi large form.*

Best is to use **a form library** instead of making each an independent state. I have used **formik**, it doesnt require a state management to use, pre-built validation with or without yup. (when your form grows, which in your case >20 inputs)

Comment: Thanks very helpfull. Can you ellaborate on this? "As mentioned above, be careful with closure, (state is not updated properly) I will advice to use a setState((prevState)=>return your modified state). useReducer has more control for you to setState."

Comment: Is you recommendation if not going for a forms library then use useReducer ?

Comment: For sure, useEffect is a closure. It is designed that way, when your first render, the closure will get a snapshot of everything outside. So, everything outside is updated will not update the snapshot of a closure, so, you have to add it in the dependency, the little array, in your useEffect, or use the setState variant that I included in my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I will start reading up on what closures are.

Comment: My personal recommendation is: go with the normal hook first, if you really need a lot of different way to set state, go with the useReducer, so far, I have used useState everywhere and still doing good. But for a form like yours with 20 inputs. best is go with form library.

Comment: Check out formik, with the useFormik hook. It will save you a lot of time. If you need a guide, juz comment here. I see what can i help.

Comment: I can see we allready have react-hook-forms I properly go for that. Just one thing that irretates me is it only returns strings, so I have to do a lot of parsing. Same for both Formik and REACT i guess. I wanted to see react hook forms vs formik there is a good article here: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hook-form-vs-formik-a-technical-and-performance-comparison/

Comment: Hm~ didnt try react-hook-form before, I have developed a habit of not to dwell into the latest shinny thing, but if it suits your team and you then why not. useState and useReducer(for custom setState) are your least worry, personally i find that useState has sufficed most of my need.

Comment: I did checkout the react-hook-form website, their showcase is quite impressive. I didnt try it before, but best practice, is to go to their github page to check their issues, see what will be the potential issues you will be facing.